# On symmetric expressions of polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

> $\alpha, \beta,  \gamma$ are the roots of equation $x^3+px^2+qx+r=0$ . Find $$\sum{\frac{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}{\alpha+\beta}}.$$

I can solve the symmetric expression by :
$$\frac{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}{\alpha+\beta} = (\alpha+\beta) -\frac{2\alpha \beta}{(\alpha+\beta) }.$$

Then,  advance forward.  But I wanted to know,  if there is any other simpler method.  I've seen such symmetric expressions solved by multiplying the inner terms and simpler terms pop out . But here I cannot...

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You could simplify the second term using that $\,\alpha\beta=-r / \gamma\,$ and $\,\alpha+\beta=-p-\gamma\,$ (btw, there is no square in the denominator), then decompose $\,1 / ( \gamma(p+\gamma) )\,$ into partial fractions.

Comment: @dxiv... I know that method... But,  I wanted to know if there are any simplification of the expression.  Like - in $\sum(\alpha-\beta) ^2$ , we can apply formula and break the term and easily get $2\sum {\alpha}^2 -2\sum \alpha \beta$ ... Anything like that applicable here?

Comment: Elaborated some more on my comment in an answer, since it got too long. But I don't know that you'll find an entirely painless way to work it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Following up on my comment, too long to post as one*.)

> $\frac{(\alpha) ^2+(\beta) ^2}{\alpha+\beta} = (\alpha+\beta) -\frac{2\alpha \beta}{(\alpha+\beta) }$

Also using that $\,\alpha\beta=-r /\gamma\,$ and $\,\alpha+\beta=-p-\gamma\,$:

$$
A = \sum \frac{\alpha ^2+\beta ^2}{\alpha+\beta} = \sum \left((\alpha+\beta) -\frac{2\alpha \beta}{\alpha+\beta} \right) = 2 \underbrace{\,\sum \alpha\,}_{=\,-p} + 2r \underbrace{\,\sum \frac{1}{\alpha(p+\alpha)}\,}_{= \,B}
$$

Since $\,\dfrac{1}{\alpha(p+\alpha)}=\dfrac{1}{p}\left(\dfrac{1}{\alpha}-\dfrac{1}{p+\alpha}\right)\,$:

$$
B = \frac{1}{p}\left(\underbrace{\,\sum \frac{1}{\alpha}\,}_{=C} - \underbrace{\,\sum \frac{1}{p+\alpha}\,}_{= D}\right)
$$

$\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\,$ are the roots of the [reciprocal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial#Properties) $\,x^3 f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 1+px+qx^2+rx^3\,$, so:

$$
C = \sum \frac{1}{\alpha} = -\frac{q}{r}
$$

$p+\alpha$ are the roots of $\,f(x-p) = x^3 - 2 p x^2 + (p^2 + q) x - p q + r\,$, so:

$$
D = \sum \frac{1}{p+\alpha}=-\frac{p^2 + q}{- p q + r}
$$

What's left is to piece it all back together, and also cover the special cases like $\,r=0\,$.

Comment: Woah...great... Didn't think of it this way ...